# separating environments for concurrent users using JMeter & selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can I separate environment for each JMeter thread using webdriver to test ASP.net website? I am trying to login (using different users with table file) and the tests fails because the cookies that saved from one thread (i.e browser window) interrupting the other threads.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're looking to get answers from the great community here, please make sure you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Try to be as specific as possible, for example by showing a short code snippet that doesn't behave as expected and error logs that can help users answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally JMeter threads (virtual users) don't share any data, see [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) concept for more details.

When it comes to [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) each JMeter Thread should kick off a separate browser instance hence there should not be any clashes as each browser should be tied to a different user having its own credentials, cookies, cache, etc.

---

In general I would recommened reconsidering your test design, according to the WebDriver Sampler [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#Introduction):

> Note: **It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.**

Browsers are **very** resource intensive so it is unlikely you will be able to kick off more than 10 browsers using mid-range laptop while using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you will be able to mimic several hundreds or even thousands of virtual users. So I would recommend creating the main load using HTTP Request samplers and use 1-2 WebDriver Sampler instances to measure page rendering speed while system is under the load.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for more information on testing ASP.NET web applications using JMeter.